# How to swipe down a UIViewController from another

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, drag

I don't know if the title is explicit so i'm going to explain it more here.
I have at the moment an **`UIViewController`**, and a **`UIButton`** linked to a **`IBAction`** that fires another `UIViewController`. I would like to avoid this step of clicking by making the user swipe up, like dragging the other `UIViewController`. Everything i found was only **`UIGestureRecognizer`** but i can't find any controls or any tutorials to drag the **`UIViewController`**. 
Basically, if i formulate this child-way, i would like to slide a **`UIViewcontroller`** from the bottom, with a one finger gesture, and that the **`UIViewController`** does follow my finger.
Thanks for your help !

EDIT : I don't use Storyboards, btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

import QuartzCore framework and do this for what u want like a window appears from bottom like in ios7 control center

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        upwardView=[[UIView alloc]init];
        upwardView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];


        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
        gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    -(void)didSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
    {
        [upwardView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 265, 320, 230)];
        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
        [animation setDuration:.50];
        [animation setDelegate:self];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        CALayer *layer = [upwardView layer];
        [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
        [self.view.window addSubview:upwardView];
    }
```

Comment: Does the view follows the finger ? Or does it present the view after i swiped ? and where do i put the first piece of code ? viewDidLoad ?

Comment: I have a UITableView in the parent ViewController, how can i limit the area of the swipe ? It seems like it doesn't work for the moment

Comment: @RaphMaz -i have put the the swipe gesture on tableviewcell if u will swipe on the down side on the cell then it will move to the next page

Comment: It doesn't work :/ Do i have to set a Delegate or something ? Can't we just limit the area of the swipe ?

Comment: @RaphMaz- what do u have..? where u put the swipe gesture in viewcontroller. and have u added navigation controller in your app delegate...?

Comment: Why UINavigationController ? It's just a UIViewController that pushes another, but i want to push it swipe-way

Comment: @RaphMaz - without navigation controller you can't push the viewcontroller from one to another

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31921/discussion-between-vivek-sehrawat-and-raph-maz)