# Drag up Child View Controller with finger and lock after point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement a smooth transition between two view controllers. What I want to do is have a UIView on the bottom of VC 1. When a user swipes/drags the view upwards, VC 2 will be modally presented. What I want to have happen is as the user drags the view upwards, the view will follow the finger and VC 2 will be dragged onto the screen. As soon as the users finger has gone past a point and then been released, I want it to then lock in place.

I have successfully implemented a UIGestureRecognizer for when a user swipes up on the view. It then presents. There are only two problems with this:

1) It does not transition with the user's finger
2) There are only 4 modal transition styles (Cover Vertical, Flip Horizontal, Cross Dissolve and Partial Curl) - none of which I want to use. I want it to slide up.

I have researched and found this question [How to swipe down a UIViewController from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162849/how-to-swipe-down-a-uiviewcontroller-from-another) however it hasn't helped as it presents a UIView rather than a UIViewController!

If anyone has any suggestions or example bits of code form someone who has done this before that would be great!

Thank you!

Comment: hi falky, i also need to implement this . have you got the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` to do the animation which you want to do, these links can be the good starting point [ios 7 custom transition](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-custom-transitions/)
and [Custom UIViewController Transitions](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/) and watch WWDC 2013 session 218 video `Custom Transitions Using View Controllers`

Comment: But will these allow you to actually drag the view controller upwards? Or is it just swipe up, then perform the upwards animation? THanks for your suggestions though I'll watch the video.